# Can I inject CSS with a chrome extension in a content.js script or using the Content scripts petameter in the manifest.json file?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I was recently making my first chrome extension when I had the idea to make one that changes a websites CSS e.g. redo chrome main menu in my style

My code so far:

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "script": ["scripts/script.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "css": ["my-styles.css"]
    
    }
  ]
}
```

my-style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Flow+Circular&family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap');


*{
    font-family: 'Flow Circular';
}
```

I went to a new webpage to see the new font but nothing was changed I am not sure if there is anything needed to activate it but what I did was tap on the extension icon to load the popup

Comment: The `action` key in `manifest.json` doesn't have a `script` property. You either used ChatGPT to write the extension for you, or you didn't read the documentation carefully enough. See [chrome.action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/)

Comment: Update: it now works on my html website but no other website even though I set it to all sites so something is different